# Boundary value analysis in C++ with CppUnit

Tags: unit-testing, limit, cppunit, boundary, epsilon

I'm trying to implement boundary tests in CppUnit. I want to check the limit value itself as well as the boundaries around this limit.

For the upper boundary I wanted to add the smallest inkrement possible. For `double` this increment can be accessed with

```
numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()
```

However, if I add epsilon to my limit I get Not-a-Number (NaN) as result:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const double WARNING_LIMIT = 8000.0;

int main(void) {

double warningLowerLimit = WARNING_LIMIT - numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();

if(warningLowerLimit < WARNING_LIMIT ) {
    cout << "lower" << endl;
}
else if (warningLowerLimit > WARNING_LIMIT) {
    cout << "upper" << endl;
}
else if ( fabs(warningLowerLimit) < 0.001) {
    cout << "same" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "NaN" << endl; // <-- result
}

}
```

Can somebody please explain me, why the result is not lower that the limit?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
else if ( fabs(warningLowerLimit) < 0.001) {
    cout << "same" << endl;
}
```

That should be

```
fabs(warningLowerLimit - WARNING_LIMIT)
```

there. Without checking the difference, you get to the `cout << "NaN"` if `warningLowerLimit == WARNING_LIMIT` for example.